# Does perforce supports file streams on Windows?

Tags: filestream, ntfs, perforce, data-stream

Does Perforce supports [file streams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364404(VS.85).aspx) on Windows, on NTFS?

Comment: These are also commonly referred to "alternate data streams" though that doesn't provide me much more info.  I don't know, curious to see if anyone has a definitive answer.

Comment: Since you mention "support" in your question: why don't you write to support@perforce.com? Seriously, Perforce's support rocks and I am sure they are even willing to answer questions if you are not (yet) a customer.

Comment: I'd second contacting Perforce directly. Their service is what makes Perforce paid for and it's well worth it.

Comment: Can you provide more information please. Why do you want to know this? Also, +1 for support@perforce.com - they are excellent and prompt and what you pay for.

Comment: I just emailed them. I will post the answer here, I'm sure other will benefit from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got a response from Perforce:

Perforce does not have any special support for NTFS Alternate Data Streams.

This means that you will lose any additional data stream when you submit a file into perforce.

Comment: I thought that would be answer as P4 is cross-platform. P4 defers some things to the local file system, i.e., case-sensitivity, but supporting NTFS data streams is something *additional* and special to Windows-only servers (I would not support it if I had cross-platform server software).

Comment: They support OS X resource forks - ~some thing but on Mac.

Comment: OS X resource forks are normal and are **often** used.  I have been using NTFS since it first shipped and have never used NTFS Alternate Data Streams.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to resurrect such an old thread, but I found a workaround that will allow Perforce clients (P4/P4V) to create ADS data.

Chapter 2 of the Perforce Users Guide has a section titled "Mapping files to different locations in the workspace". This section covers how to remap the depot to the workspace and vice-versa.

Let's assume that you want to store some asset metadata with your files in Perforce. You create a tool that generates an ADS called **asset.meta** such that your filenames are of the form **file.ext:asset.meta**.

If you modify your Perforce Workspace to include the following:

```
//depot/....asset.meta //CLIENT/...:asset.meta
```

This will take ADS asset.meta streams and create files for them in Perforce.

foo.txt with an asset.meta ADS gets stored as 2 files in the depot: foo.txt and foo.txt.asset.meta. When you sync them down, they end joined correctly.

Now there are 2 caviats to be aware of.

1.) P4V will not see the ADSs. You have to add them manually through P4, the P4API or some other explicit mechanism.

2.) If the base file (foo.txt from our example) is not marked writable, you will not be able to sync the ADS.

You will have to deal with #1 in whatever way you want. #2 is trickier IMO. You can +w the main files so they are always writable on the client (if your workflows can accommodate that), or you can write a custom sync routine that handles making files read-only or read-write as necessary.

I may respond to this if I hear any good ideas from Perforce other than the ones mentioned above, but considering how high this page shows up in Google when searching for "Perforce Alternate Data Stream", I thought this might help someone.